# iOS: Display notification message when application opens

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I have a textview and an imageview in my app so i can display the notification text and the image that i want to show. i receive this image from a url that i send via the notification. When i send notifications to my application and the app isn't running, the textview and the imageview doesnt show the content, but when the app is running or when the app state is in background the content updates.

I suppose that i have to configure the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function when the app starts in order to update the fields of the view controller. 
how can i do that? and why the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` function doesnt update the view when the app starts and updates the view only in two states (active & background)?

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
NSLog(@"New notification received!");

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

//Notification recieved & handle the aps
NSDictionary * notificationDict = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"refreshView" object:notificationDict];
NSString * alertString = [notificationDict objectForKey:@"alert"];
NSString * serverUrl = [notificationDict objectForKey:@"acme"];

NSLog(@"Notification text is: %@", alertString);

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: alertString forKey: @"alertMSG"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

//handle the notification when the app is active, inactive or in background
if ( application.applicationState ==  UIApplicationStateActive )
{
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController2"];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
else if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive)
{
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController2"];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
else //ApplicationState Background
{
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController2"];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

}

**EDIT:**

I have configure the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to starts my controller when the app is launched from a notification, but the content still doesn't update beside the fact that i have signed an observer between the view controller and the app delegate. what am i missing ?

here is the code :

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:  (NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

if (launchOptions != nil)
        {               
            NSDictionary * dictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
            if (dictionary != nil)
            {
                [self handleRemoteNotification:dictionary];
            }
        }
}

-(void)handleRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)payload{
    NSDictionary * notificationDict = [payload objectForKey:@"aps"]; //extract some information from payload
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"refreshView" object:notificationDict];

UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController2"];
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;}
```

ViewController2.m:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

//Observer for remote notifications
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(refreshView:)  name:@"refreshView" object: nil];

notifTextf.delegate = self;
```

}

```
//Update View when notification is received
-(void)refreshView:(NSNotification *) notification
{
// Do whatever you like to respond to text changes here.

NSLog(@"observer notification message text is: %@", [notification.object objectForKey:@"alert"]);
NSLog(@"observer notification message url is: %@", [notification.object objectForKey:@"acme"]);


[self.notifTextf setText: [notification.object objectForKey:@"alert"]];

//Download image from Url sended by notification and display it
NSString * imageurl = [notification.object objectForKey:@"acme"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageurl];
self.notifImg.image = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:[CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:url]];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why the didReceiveRemoteNotification function doesnt update the view
>   when the app starts and updates the view only in two states (active &
>   background)?

If the app is not running when a push notification arrives, the system launches the app and provides the appropriate information in the launch options dictionary. The app does not call `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` method to handle that push notification. Instead, your implementation of the `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method needs to get the push notification payload data and respond appropriately.

Implement the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` method instead whenever possible (iOS 7 and above).

Unlike the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` method, which is called only when your app is running in the foreground, the system calls the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` method when your app is running in the foreground or background. In addition, if you enabled the remote notifications background mode (to support this mode, include the `UIBackgroundModes` key with the `remote-notification` value in your app’s `Info.plist` file), the system launches your app (or wakes it from the suspended state) and puts it in the background state when a push notification arrives. However, the system does not automatically launch your app if the user has force-quit it. In that situation, the user must relaunch your app or restart the device before the system attempts to launch your app automatically again.

[Continue reading...](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/index.html)

Comment: very usefull answer! i ve managed to start a view controller when the app starts from a notification but the content doesnt update. I have edit the question if you want to check it out!

Comment: In `handleRemoteNotification:` you are posting the `refreshView` notification before instantiating the view controller and therefore `refreshView:` is not called. Try to post the notification from the completion block in `presentViewController:animated:completion:` to be sure that the view controller's `viewDidLoad` method has executed and therefore it has registered to receive the notification.

Comment: thanks! it worked. i thought that the code after the line 
'[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];' doesn't excecute